# Can I put a value in a specific index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I use React. I want to make `table`

I want to make like this table.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |

```
import react from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const array = [
    {value : 1},
    {value : 2},
    {value : 3},
    {value : 4},
    {value : 5},
    {value : 5},
  ];

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column A</th>
          <th>Column B</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        // I don't know
      </tbody>
    </table>
  )
};
```

```
        {array.map(value => {????})}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Expected output]

```
 <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Column A</th>
              <th>Column B</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {array.map((item, index)=>{
              if(index%2===0){
                return <tr>
                  <td>{item.value}</td>
                  <td>{array[index+1].value}</td>
                </tr> 
              }
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
```